# Multiplying out `Odds` values from an array within JSON

Tags: javascript, html

I get a json Array  from url like this

```
{"soccerodds2017":[
    {"Selections":"Chelsea","Odds":"1.44"},
    {"Selections":"Wolverhampton","Odds":"2.33"},
    {"Selections":"Walsall","Odds":"2.70"}
]}
```

I will like to multiply the odds by 10
example: `10*1.44*2.33*2.70` and get the total. How to do that in javascripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` just set initial value of accumulator to 10 and then multiply each `e.Odds` value.

```js
var obj = {"soccerodds2017":[{"Selections":"Chelsea","Odds":"1.44"},{"Selections":"Wolverhampton","Odds":"2.33"},{"Selections":"Walsall","Odds":"2.70"}]}

var total = obj.soccerodds2017.reduce(function(r, e) {
  return r * +e.Odds
}, 10)

console.log(total)
```

Comment: nice answer! I like it!

Comment: @funcoding Thanks.

Comment: reducing answer to 2 decimal places?

Comment: There are few ways to round up number here are some https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1840/

Comment: @meandme `total = +total.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic function to handle processing the multiplication.

```js
var data = { "soccerodds2017": [
  { "Selections" : "Chelsea",       "Odds": "1.44" },
  { "Selections" : "Wolverhampton", "Odds": "2.33" },
  { "Selections" : "Walsall",       "Odds": "2.70" }
]};

console.log(calculate(data['soccerodds2017'], 'Odds', (x, y) => x * parseFloat(y), 10));

function calculate(data, prop, fn, initVal) {
  return data.reduce((total, value) => fn.call(this, total, value[prop]), initVal || 0);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

You can also make a calculator class to handle all the boilerplate logic for you.

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(type = 'float') {
    this.type = type;
  }
  calc(data, prop, op, initVal) {
    initVal = initVal || 0;
    switch (op) {
      case 'add' : return this.__calculate__(data, prop, this.constructor.add, initVal);
      case 'sub' : return this.__calculate__(data, prop, this.constructor.sub, initVal);
      case 'mul' : return this.__calculate__(data, prop, this.constructor.mul, initVal);
      case 'div' : return this.__calculate__(data, prop, this.constructor.div, initVal);
      throw Error('Operation not supported');
    }
  }
  __calculate__(data, prop, fn, initVal) {
    return data.reduce((total, value) => fn.call(this, total, prop ? value[prop] : value), initVal);
  }
}

class IntegerCalculator extends Calculator {
  constructor() {
    super('int')
  }
  static add(x, y)   { return x + parseInt(y, 10); }
  static sub(x, y)   { return x - parseInt(y, 10); }
  static mul(x, y)   { return x * parseInt(y, 10); }
  static div(x, y)   { return x / parseInt(y, 10); }
}

class FloatCalculator extends Calculator {
  constructor() {
    super('float')
  }
  static add(x, y) { return x + parseFloat(y); }
  static sub(x, y) { return x - parseFloat(y); }
  static mul(x, y) { return x * parseFloat(y); }
  static div(x, y) { return x / parseFloat(y); }
}

var floatCalc = new FloatCalculator();
var data = { "soccerodds2017": [
  { "Selections" : "Chelsea",       "Odds": "1.44" },
  { "Selections" : "Wolverhampton", "Odds": "2.33" },
  { "Selections" : "Walsall",       "Odds": "2.70" }
]};

console.log(floatCalc.calc(data['soccerodds2017'], 'Odds', 'mul', 10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```